# VBscript equivalent of a simple ruby script

Tags: ruby, parsing, vbscript

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950499/parsing-position-files-in-ruby) about parsing a file in ruby.  I accepted an answer and wrote the following ruby script:

```
file = File.open('X:myfile.txt', 'r')
file.each_line do |line|
    ccyy = line[53...57]
    mmdd = line[57...61]
    line[53...57] = mmdd
    line[57...61] = ccyy
    File.open('c:\myfile_MODIFIED.txt', 'a') do |f2|  
        f2.puts line
    end
end
```

This script will run in production and change the file, however, production is a windows box and only vbscript is allowed to run on it. Unfortunatley I havn't written anything in VB before.  Can someone help in converting the meat of above code to vb?

What I have so far is:

```
Dim oFolder, oFile, sText, ots

Set OFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = OFSO.GetFolder("X:\myfolder")
Set RegXP=New RegExp
RegXP.IgnoreCase=1
RegXP.Pattern="PROD_FILE_\d+.txt"



For Each oFile in oFolder.Files 
    If (RegXP.test(oFile.Name)) Then
        WScript.Echo oFile.Name
        set ots = OFSO.opentextfile(oFile)
        Do While Not ots.AtEndOfStream
            sText = ots.ReadLine
                  'read file line by line. change characters in the line. write line to new file'   
        Loop
        ots.close

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're 90% of the way there.

Since VBScript doesn't provide direct random access to string contents, you need to use some functions to do the string manipulation.

I'd go with [Mid](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/VBScript/13951.asp) and [Left](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/VBScript/13951.asp).

E.g.

```
dim a, b
a = "Hello, World!"
b = left( mid( a, 8 ), 5 )
wscript.echo(b)
```

Output: `World`

Comment: thanks. but that still doesnt replace the string. from your example....say I am trying to replace 4th character of a with 6th character of a

Comment: just break it into 4 chunks: start, ccyy, mmdd, end. then put it back together as `start & mmdd & ccyy & end`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Replace or Mid?

```
 ''Replace(expression, find, replace [, start ] [, count ] [, compare ] )
 Replace(sText,"a","b") 

 Mid(sText,4,1)=Mid(sText,6,1)
```